# The Reference numbers are disappeared. Please help

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

The number for each list of Ref is not shown. Please help me.
[image: The number in front of each list of Ref are disappeared.]

```
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% This is a simple template for a LaTeX document using the "article" class.
% See "book", "report", "letter" for other types of document.

\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage{amsmath}% Added by Palm for writing Math symbols

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

%%% Examples of Article customizations
% These packages are optional, depending whether you want the features they provide.
% See the LaTeX Companion or other references for full information.

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
% \geometry{margin=2in} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round
% \geometry{landscape} % set up the page for landscape
%   read geometry.pdf for detailed page layout information

\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options

% \usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{array} % for better arrays (eg matrices) in maths
\usepackage{paralist} % very flexible & customisable lists (eg. enumerate/itemize, etc.)
\usepackage{verbatim} % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
\usepackage{subfig} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float
% These packages are all incorporated in the memoir class to one degree or another...

%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % This should be set AFTER setting up the page geometry
\pagestyle{fancy} % options: empty , plain , fancy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % customise the layout...
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}

%%% SECTION TITLE APPEARANCE
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} % (See the fntguide.pdf for font help)
% (This matches ConTeXt defaults)

%%% ToC (table of contents) APPEARANCE
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % Put the bibliography in the ToC
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft} % Alter the style of the Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape} % No bold!
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
  \small    
  \textbf{\textit{Keywords:}} #1
}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%% END Article customizations

%%% The "real" document content comes below...

\title{...

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please provide the `MWE` which produce the same output as what you are suffering else provide one or two entries from your `bib` file or generated `bbl` file....

Answer (score 1):

You are loading both the `apacite` and the `natbib` package (and then use a style that is was not written with either package in mind). Those two packages are incompatible (at least when they are used as in your preamble) – one of the two has to go.

- If you want APA 6th edition citations,

  - **either** only load `\usepackage{apacite}`, remove the `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`, replace `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` with `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and replace all `\citep` with `\cite` and `\citet` with `\citeA`
  - **or** load `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` to obtain a `natbib` mode, remove the `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` and replace `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` with `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`.
- If you don't want APA 6th edition citations and prefer numeric citations, remove `\usepackage{apacite}` and consider replacing `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` with its `natbib` counterpart `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`.